# Firebase rxfire subscription check my code

Tags: typescript, firebase, rxjs

Hi since rxfire is rather new to firebase I just want to check that this is the best way to subscribe to changes with it, the code below works.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/rxfire/docs/database.md

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { database, initializeApp } from 'firebase';
import { stateChanges, ListenEvent, object } from 'rxfire/database';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

  const db = firebase.database();
  const ref = db.ref('_data');
  stateChanges(ref).subscribe(change => {

    // console.log(change);
    //console.log(change.snapshot.key);
    //console.log(change.snapshot.val());

    if (change.snapshot.key == '_appConfig') {
      this._appConfig = change.snapshot.val();
      console.log(this._appConfig);
    }


  });
```

Blog ref: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/09/introducing-rxfire-easy-async-firebase.html

Comment: Questions seeking improvements/feedback for working code belong on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Did you write this or did you happen to find it on the net?

Comment: From console.log(change) its my code